# Phonegap Build Error "plugin unsupported: splashscreen"

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am Using PhonegapBuild Not  eclipse for build my application.

We are not using any custom plugin. I read the post about plugin but i think it's for custom plugin so i didn't change anything in XML and it gives me error "`plugin unsupported: splashscreen`" So can any one help me how to get rid of it.

In Config.xml splash plugin line is same as mentioned in docs and it's as below

For Android:

```
<gap:plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

For IOS:

```
<gap:plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
```

Please help me..

Screenshot is below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all plugin from my config.xml for Android as well IOS also.Then i successfully upload my Zip file for Build and its Build and Working Fine in Device..

Comment: Hi there! Please consider accepting your answer if it really worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you must be confused with the feauture and the plugin 
Try using the following for the feauture

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

Try using the following for the plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" version="2.1.0" />
```

But I also have [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762995/splashscreen-not-working-on-phonegap-build-cli-5-2-0?noredirect=1#comment53461541_32762995) with my splashscreen, so it may not be 100% correct. My problem is that my images are not being recognized.