# Splashscreen not working on Phonegap Build cli-5.2.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, splash-screen

I use Phonegap for over a year and I had no problem with my Splashscreen until now. I decided to move from 3.7.0 to cli-5.2.0 (I think it would make no difference even if it was cli-5.1.1) and I cannot make my SplashScreen work. 
I have read [**here**](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/splashscreen-not-working-on-android) that in cli-5.1.1 and above you need the new splashscreen plugin from npm in order to make it work (until now all I had to do was to specify the paths of splashscreen images). 
So my config file ended up in something like this:

```
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" width="320" height="426" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" width="320" height="470" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" width="480" height="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xdpi.png" width="720" height="960" />

.....

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="748" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1004" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />

    <!-- splashscreen delay -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />    
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>


    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

.....

    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
```

I tried too many versions that I cannot even remember them. Can anyone see where the problem is, or has to suggest anything else? 
 
I want to specify that I do not use any default SplashScreen image (I tried to set one, but I had no luck. Besides until 3.7.0 it had no use, so why to have now) and I do not use any kind of javascript to show/hide the splashscreen. 
When my app starts, it shows a black screen for about 5sec(the time the splashscreen should appear) and then my app starts normally from the first screen

**EDITED:**

The full config file is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns     = "hxxp://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "hxxp://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "..."
        versionCode   = "100"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>...</name>

    <description>...</description>

    <author href="..." email="...">...</author>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
        <string>1.0.0</string>
    </gap:config-file>


    <!-- ANDROID ICONS -->
    <icon density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" width="48" height="48" />
    <icon density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" width="96" height="96" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" width="144" height="144" />

    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" width="320" height="426" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" width="320" height="470" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" width="480" height="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xdpi.png" width="720" height="960" />



    <!-- IOS ICONS -->
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="748" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1004" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />

    <!-- splashscreen delay -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />    
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>


    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>

    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>   


<access origin="*" />


    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
</widget>
```

**EDITED 2:**

Today I tested it on IOS. The splashscreen shows up but the app stucks there. It does not disables the splashscreen after 5sec as it should do.
I cannot figure out what is happening. I am going back on 3.7.0 until it is solved.

Comment: Is the issue occuring on androids only ? or iPhones as well.

Comment: I have no IPhone with me for these days but I suppose it is the same in both OS

Comment: can you share full xml.config file..?

Comment: I posted it on **EDITED** on my initial question

Comment: @tzes, I followed the link you provided. Petra, the responder, is usually correct on problems. However, your assumption that 5.1.1 and 5.2.0 are similar is incorrect. On your config.xml the *feature* elements are ONLY intended for debugging. They are not the problem, but noise. I would re-read the documentation. I think you are missing the [default splash screen](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, it is true that I ommited the default splash screen, but it was done on purpose. The tutorial in which you reffer to says that **Unless otherwise specified in a config.xml, each platform will try to use the default splash.png during compilation** 
Since I specify the images that should be used for splashscreen, there is no reason to declare the default splascreen image. I used to ommit it in the previous versions of phonegap too, and there was no problem. But now it seems as if the images are not being recognized
And that's why I am not sure what is going on

Comment: Over the last few days, Cordova and Phonegap have update the default setting for compile systems. This has cause numerous problems for people. I have given the same advice to dozens of people. It may help you on this as well. I have written this up in an FAQ, but the last few days have cause be to write [Current Tripping Points to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md); **See #2 Not setting compiler version**. In short, not setting the version will cause  cascading error. Again, this has been the case problems.

Comment: I specify the **compiler version**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />` and I also tried to specify the plugins versions. No Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem but I know an easy fix for your stuck iOS splashscreen:

In your main html file:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //Hide Splashscreen 
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

I know you mentioned you don't use js to show/hide the splashscreen, but for iOS you are forced to :( (at least in my experience)